# What is nt.stat_result?

Tags: python, windows

What kind of object is `nt.stat_result` ?

```
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0L, st_atime=1305043675L, st_mtime=1305043677L, st_ctime=1305043675L)
```

I see that I can access each element by dot notation. But can't understand what is all this about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by object type.
Running `help(nt)` in the my IDLE environment on Windows displays the below help text:

```
    class stat_result(__builtin__.object)
     |  stat_result: Result from stat or lstat.
     |  
     |  This object may be accessed either as a tuple of
     |    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime)
     |  or via the attributes st_mode, st_ino, st_dev, st_nlink, st_uid, and so on.
```

You can try the same on your windows box and read the complete help. The help text mentions that the field st_ino indicates the inode number of the file , you can refer to help of `nt` module for description of other attributes.

Comment: so `nt` is a module and `stat_result` is class. `os.stat` returns an instance of that class.

Comment: `st_nlink` is attribute or function?

Comment: the doc says it is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be: this is a result, returned from [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) call on windows. Check the `os.stat` documentation for the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As with other python classes of a similiar nature, it behaves similarly to the namedtuple class in the collections module introduced in python 2.6. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) helped me in accessing and working with objects like nt.stat_result.